# this.setState second argument with a setTimeout

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, settimeout

I am trying to manipulate the state of my component. The state contains a BOOL isCoping which is set to false initially, after clicking I want the state isCoping to change to true and then after 2 seconds I want it to change back to true.

The constructor is

```
constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isCoping : false
        }
    }
```

and handleClick is as follows:

```
handleClick = (e) => {
        this.setState({isCoping : true}
        , setTimeout(()=> {this.setState({isCoping : false})}, 2000)
        )
    }
```

Can someone please let me know what am I doing wrong? It is not working. The initially the isCoping does get changed to TRUE but it doesn't revert back to FALSE after 2 seconds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cause second agrument must a function. Try this

```
handleClick = (e) => {
   this.setState(
     {isCoping : true},
     () => setTimeout(()=> {this.setState({isCoping : false})}, 2000)
   )
}
```